# ImportError: cannot import name 'loads' from 'json' (unknown location)

Tags: python, json

Previos title was: 
`AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'`
I changed it because it looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082730/module-object-has-no-attribute-loads-while-parsing-json-using-python) but at the link that i provided, the problem seems that the person was having a file called `json.py` that was tricking the import to think that is importing a local file and not the json from standard library. My problem is that I don't have any local file called `json.py`;

I am wondering if it has to do anything related to PATH or the structure of my project. Any suggestion might help.

error traceback:

```
  File "D:\Me\IdeaProjects\src\app\repositories\user_repository.py", line 14, in get_user
    user = json.loads(file.read())
```

I am running the code in Windows 10, and intelliJ ide.

Python version: 3.7.4

Tried the code from the official documentation [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```py
import json
def as_complex(dct):
    if '__complex__' in dct:
        return complex(dct['real'], dct['imag'])
    return dct

json.loads('{"__complex__": true, "real": 1, "imag": 2}', object_hook=as_complex)
```

And got this error as well:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads('{"__complex__": true, "real": 1, "imag": 2}',object_hook=as_complex)
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'
```

When I try to import `loads` explicitly i get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'loads' from 'json' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Add the full error traceback that occurs when you try to import

Comment: What's the output of `print(str(json))` at the point of failure?

Comment: whas OS are you running on? What version of python? what do you get from a terminal if you echo $PYTHONPATH? Do you work with virtualenvs? As is, it is impossible to answer

Comment: Added some more info and i tried the code from the official documentation and i still get the same Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had python installed in Admin account in window 10 and it was installed with Admin privileges, but when i used in another account I could not use the packages, however installing the python in the current account did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import loads explicitly:

```
import json
from json import loads
```

Comment: Then i get this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'loads' from 'json' (unknown location)`

Comment: Try to install json again or update it maybe not all of the json library is included in your environment.

Comment: Json is part of the standard library.

Comment: So thing is that python can't find loads because it is not included in the expected location means, you have to get the module in to the environment you are working in.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you run any other Python code that does not use json in this File you are working in?

Comment: Yes, i can do that.

Comment: Well I am not sure what the exact problem is but maybe it helps to install python to the exact same file location again and remove the current one. That's what I would do.