# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, datetime

How can I write this code in a class?

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today().year
my_date = input().split('/')

if int(my_date[1]) > 12 or int(my_date[2]) > 31:
    print('WRONG')
else:
    my_age = now - int(my_date[0])
    print(int(my_age))
```

when I write it in a class it doesn't work propery

Comment: Is your file named ``datetime.py``?

Comment: Can you share the class that causes this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['module' object has no attribute 'loads' while parsing JSON using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082730/module-object-has-no-attribute-loads-while-parsing-json-using-python)

Comment: I had a file named datetime.py and deleted it and the error has gone, but my code in class doesn't work yet

Comment: How can I write this in a class?

Comment: There is no ``class`` in this code, and it's hard to tell where there should be one. Please ask a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: If the error has gone, you'd better delete this answer. You will than be able to ask a new one, focusing the new problems.