# I imported json but builtins.AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, json, import

I have [same problem like there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082730/module-object-has-no-attribute-loads-while-parsing-json-using-python/69774188#69774188). My error call is *builtins.AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'* but I imported json as first so what is wrong?

```
import json

f = open('data.json')

data = json.load(f) 

for i in data['emp_details']:
    print(i)
 
f.close()
```

Comment: @PedroMaia  That's clearly the wrong answer, since he's loading from a file not a string.

Comment: You almost certainly have your own file called `json.py` in your project.  You are importing that one, not the standard library `json`.  You need to rename that file.

Answer (score 0):

you have a `json` module(folder) in your project folder (root path of your project ), rename it

or you have a file that name is `json.py` , rename it

```
(root of project)
  |
  | main.py
  |
  | json.py
  |
  |------ json 
  |       |- __init__.py
  |       |- other file.py
```